# How can I mock Prisma client with es6 (Without typescript) in jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, orm, jestjs, prisma

The Prisma Documentation has examples of mocking the client and doing unit testing using jest and typescript. Is there any way to mock the client in jest without using TypeScript?

I would be grateful if you can give a simple example.

Small Thing to add: I am using dependency injection in my project in all the functions that use the prisma.

Comment: Show the code under test

Comment: Could you elaborate on what aspect of the [unit testing docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing) you're having trouble adopting? Aside from the declarative types/interfaces, there's not much that's different between typescript and javascript.  As another user mentioned, some code might also be of help.

Comment: I am not very familiar with TypeScript syntax. So it all seems strange to me. Specifically the import of the modules and the context.ts file. My code is just a simple function that adds an entire to the database using Prisma client which is passed as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

I've made a `Nodejs` demo which is equivalent to the official guide - [Unit testing (`TypeScript` version)](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing).

See: https://github.com/OctobugDemo/nodejs-prisma-unit-test

It might help.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for now:
I am manually mocking the database object and passing it to the function that uses it: I am not sure how useful this but it helps avoid making calls to the real database.

```
const mocked_db = {
    user: {
        findFirst: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(
            {
                id: 2,
                first_name: "Basel",
                last_name: "Akasha"
            }
        ))
    }
}

it("It should work blah blah bla", async () => {
    let user_details= {
       id: 2,
       first_name: "Basel",
       last_name: "Akasha"
    }
    
    let signup = await getUser(
        mocked_db // takes thew DB object is a parameter (normally you would pass your Prisma client instance)
    )

    await expect(.... // whatever you'r expect is
})'
```