# How to mock Prisma in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prisma

I have tried to follow the docs, a bunch of tutorials, StackOverflow answers etc... But none of them seem to do the trick.
How do I actually Mock a Prisma DB Connection? As i'd like to do some tests on my API for github actions and for that to happen id need to mock prisma, which uses a PostgreSQL database.
If someone has a good example on github, or anything like that, I would really appreciate it

Comment: Prisma has a [unit testing guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing) in their docs. Does that fit your use case?

Comment: Unfortunately no, i tried following that one and it simply doesn't mock Prisma, don't know if the issue is with me using js and not ts, but I highly doubt it, as I tried removing the types and generics and still didn't work

Comment: I see. Someone with a similar problem came up with [this solution mocks certain function calls inside Prisma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69721253/8855844), perhaps it might help!

Comment: Hi im incredibly sorry for replying this late lol, yea that lowkey doesn't work since id have to completely change how my connector works.
What I did was just keep a database open, but prisma doesn't seem to connect to it because I keep getting Cannot read property 'PrismaClient' of undefined. ANy reason as of why?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out @Tweeno?  I'm running into what I think is a similar issue.  I followed the singleton solution in the Prisma unit test guides, and when I run my function, it doesn't actually interact with the mocked database.  Where it should create a record and return it, it just returns undefined.

Comment: Yea, I changed to Uvu. However, im not mocking the db, im using one that i setup in my ci/cd pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently developing test for a nestJS project, if you want to look to my work here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77439558/nestjs-e2e-testing-mocking-prisma-client-with-jest-fastify/77439559#77439559)

Also if you want another way, there exist library to catch call made to db and store it to memory, if it match your use case it might work for you

https://github.com/morintd/prismock

https://github.com/demonsters/prisma-mock